# SwiftUI: How to properly animate content size change inside List?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct DynamicRectangle: View {
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: isExpanded ? 400 : 200)
            .animation(.spring())

        .onTapGesture {
            self.isExpanded.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            DynamicRectangle()
            DynamicRectangle()
            DynamicRectangle()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a tiny example that still has an obvious problem: though the size changes are smoothly animating, the List itself immediately changes its row size. Is there any workaround to make it animate the row size together with the content size I have inside?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I use a `ScrollView` it works perfectly fine:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DynamicRectangle: View {
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: isExpanded ? 400 : 200)
            .animation(.spring())

        .onTapGesture {
            self.isExpanded.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            DynamicRectangle()
            DynamicRectangle()
            DynamicRectangle()
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer `ScrollView` over `List`.

Comment: This is... unexpected. Though we do lose some List functionality (e.g. handling .onMove and .onDelete events), animations work just fine. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: I faced the same problem and I found that the animation is smoother if instead of changing the Size of the row you add another row. May not be always feasible but in my case I did not want to lose the handling of .onMove and .onDelete events